# how to send text mail in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, smtp

i want to send text not view by laravel mail , as i use simple form wth textarea to write the content of message , how to seend text or how to convert this text to view ....... thanks

```
public function sendmail(){
    $sendmessage=Input::get('message');
    //$messageView=View::make('messageview')->with('message',$sendmessage);


    Mail::send($sendmessage, array('name'=>'hossam'),function($message){
        $title=Input::get('title');
        $mail=Input::get('mailsender');

        $message->from($mail,'user');
        $message->to('webdev11111@gmail.com','hossam gamal')->subject($title);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an email view where the only thing it sends is the contents of a variable:

app/views/emails/nonview.blade.php

```
{{ $contents }}
```

Then, you can use this view whenever you want to send an email that doesn't have a view:

```
public function sendmail() {
    $from = Input::get('mailsender');
    $subject = Input::get('title');

    // 'contents' key in array matches variable name used in view
    $data = array(
        'contents' => Input::get('message')
    );

    Mail::send('emails.nonview', $data, function($message) use ($from, $subject) {
        $message->from($from, 'user');
        $message->to('webdev11111@gmail.com','hossam gamal')->subject($subject);
    });
}
```